# How to remove one controller's session attribute from another?

Tags: spring, session, controller

This is a question about sharing session between two Spring 3 controllers.

One controller handles the display of entities. It caches database select result in @SessionAttributes. Another controller handles addition and deletion of entities. The challange is to delete the session cache of the first controller, whenever the second controller adds or deletes an entity.

**Index controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/fileIndex")
@SessionAttributes(value={IndexController.INDEX_ITEM_LIST})
public class FileIndexController extends IndexController {

if(!model.containsAttribute(IndexController.INDEX_ITEM_LIST)) {
    model.addAttribute(IndexController.INDEX_ITEM_LIST, getFileList(screenObject)); // sql select 
}
screenObject.setPageItemList((List<?>) model.asMap().get(IndexController.INDEX_ITEM_LIST), pageNumber); // page of entities (subset of cached sql select)
```

**Action controller - Delete method**

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, params=ACTION_DELETE)
public ModelAndView delete(@ModelAttribute("screenObject") FileHeaderEditScreenObject screenObject, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, Locale locale) {

    try {
        fileService.deleteFile(screenObject.getFileId());
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        screenObject.addError(t.getMessage());
    }

    ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView();
    if(screenObject.getErrorCount()>0) {
        initializeScreenObject(screenObject.getFileId(), screenObject, locale, false);
        modelAndView.setViewName(WebView.FILE_HEADER_EDIT_PAGE.getViewName());
    } else {
        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/fileIndex");
    }
    model.asMap().remove(IndexController.INDEX_ITEM_LIST);  // this does not work
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SessionStatus.setComplete()` .